# Unable to install Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, angular-cli-v6

Please help me solve my problem. Thanks in advance. I am getting an error while I am trying to install angular cli.

- node - v8.11.3
- npm - 6.1.0
- windows 10 64 bit os

`E:\Workout\Angular JS 4>npm install @angular/cli@latest`

> @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall E:\Workout\Angular JS 4\node_modules@angular\cli
>   node ./bin/ng-update-message.js
>
> npm WARN angular-cli@6.0.0 No repository field. npm WARN optional
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! file bash npm ERR! path bash npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm
>   ERR! errno ENOENT npm ERR! syscall spawn bash npm ERR!
>   @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall: `node ./bin/ng-update-message.js` npm
>   ERR! spawn bash ENOENT npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: Are you trying to install it in a global way ? Are you trying to init a new angular cli project or to run an existing project ?

Comment: @alvinmeimoun new angular cli project.

Comment: try to add the global parameter to your command "npm install @angular/cli@latest -g"

Comment: yeah tried that also. But its not worked out for me. error in post install script. failed to exec postinstall script

Comment: Finally i got the solution. it because of angular-cli version issue. thanks